# Super easy and free photo sharing site

Tags: sharing, photos

I'm looking for an easy (very easy) photo sharing site where I can just pop a picture up quickly and easily AND easily share it by emailing a link.  And also people can see it without any hassles by just clicking the link.

I know nothing about any of these web photo sharing sites, except that some require software to be installed and I need one without that requirement, that's still very easy to use.

If I'm being choosy, I'd like one where there's no registration or sign up required.

Answer (score 3):

[Picasa](http://picasa.google.com) or [Flickr](http://flickr.com)

If you mind registration, you could go to [imageshack](http://imageshack.us)

Answer (score 3):

http://min.us/

Just drop your images in , super easy ? Right ?
No registration required

Answer (score 2):

[Imgur.com](http://imgur.com)

No sign-up for uploading or viewing. Allows for viewing the image directly (no webpage)

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a photosharing service, but I'd use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTM3ODI2Nzk?src=global).

It creates a local folder and you just drop in all the images. This folder can be shared between different people, and if the pics are in the public directory you can just send out links.

Comment: The Photos folder also automatically displays photos as albums IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

[TinyPic](http://www.tinypic.com) was pretty painless, but it's shutting down as of September 2019.

Answer (score 0):

- http://min.us/
- http://imgur.com/
- http://localhostr.com/

I personally use [localhostr](http://localhostr.com/) because I like how simple it is. You don't need to register and if you want, there is a tool you can download to simply take snapshots and upload with it, but you don't need it.